# How to parse multiline attributes using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have HTML content as given below:

```
content ="<p class="sub">
        Sector:
        <a href="/company/compare/00000008/">
          Capital Goods - Electrical Equipment
        </a>
<span style="margin: 16px"></span>
        Industry:
        <a href="/company/compare/00000008/00000039/">
          Electric Equipment
        </a>"
</p>
```

I want to parse `sector = Capital Goods - Electrical Equipment` and `Industry=Electric Equipment` using `BeautifulSoup` . Kindly guide me for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the texts into a structured format like `dict` with key / value pairs you can use a `dict comprhension`:

```
dict([(x.previous.strip()[:-1],x.get_text(strip=True)) for x in soup.select('p.sub a')])
```

These is selecting all `<a>` in your example, iterates the `ResultSet` for the values and also extract the associated key.

```
{'Sector': 'Capital Goods - Electrical Equipment', 'Industry': 'Electric Equipment'}
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

html ='''
<p class="sub">
   Sector:
   <a href="/company/compare/00000008/">
    Capital Goods - Electrical Equipment
   </a>
   <span style="margin: 16px">
   </span>
   Industry:
   <a href="/company/compare/00000008/00000039/">
    Electric Equipment
   </a>
   "
</p>
'''
dict([(x.previous.strip()[:-1],x.get_text(strip=True)) for x in soup.select('p.sub a')])
```